# Why we use scalar valued function in SQL

Tags: sql

If performance of Scalar valued function or any user defined  function is slower than SP's
Why we need to go through User defined function rather to go with simple SP's?

Comment: as SP is pre complied and stored it into DB that is not possible with Functions I guess!

Comment: They are different tools meant to solve the different problems. A scalar valued function returns a scalar value and a SP "returns" a resultset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDF could introduce serious performance problems when it used in JOIN or WHERE clause and query returns big amount of data

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id AND B.ExtraCode = calculateExtraCode(A.Name)
```

so for each selected row UDF will be called and problem is in invocation latency introduced by UDF call. it simply can be tested by extracting UDF body inline of SP or query, difference will be easily observed.

But if query returns small amount of data it makes sense to separate logic into UDF so code of the main query/SP will be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

What you use depends on the requirements.

**Functions (including scalar ones) can be used within queries and return a set of different types while stored procedures can only return an integer value and cannot be used within other queries**.

```
create function dbo.scalarfunc () returns varchar(20) as
begin
    declare @somevalue varchar(20)
    set @somevalue = (select top 1 name from master.sys.tables)
    return @somevalue

end
go

select * from sys.tables
where name = dbo.scalarfunc()
```

with an SP

```
create procedure dbo.someproc as 
begin
    declare @somevalue varchar(20)
    set @somevalue = (select top 1 name from master.sys.tables)
    return @somevalue
end
go

declare @somespret varchar(20)
exec @somespret = dbo.someproc
```

this causes the return to be NULL and the following message

> 'The 'someproc' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which
>   is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.'

And a proc returning an integer

```
create procedure dbo.someproc as 
begin
    declare @somevalue int
    set @somevalue = (select top 1 object_id from master.sys.tables)
    return @somevalue
end
go

declare @somespret int
exec @somespret = dbo.someproc
select @somespret
```

This works but using it in a query

select * from sys.tables
where name = dbo.someproc()

results in the message

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "dbo.someproc", or the name is ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

Because you can call a scalar valued function from inside a select query such as.

```
select f1(name), f2(id) from users
```

which is not possible in case of SPs